# XMLParsing String encoding

Tags: ios, xml, encoding

I am currently parsing a XML file containing lots of geo-data.

Basically the file contains a list of cities that may contain this example list of alternative names for foreign languages. The example shown shows a list of alternative names for Berlin:

```
        <alternateName lang="af">Berlyn</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="als">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="an">Berlín</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ang">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ar">برلين</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="arc">ܒܪܠܝܢ</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ast">Berlín</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="bar">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="be">Бэрлін</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="bg">Берлин</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="bn">বার্লিন</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="br">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="bs">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ca">Estat de Berlín</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="cs">Berlín</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="csb">Berlëno</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="cv">Берлин</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="cy">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="da">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="de">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="el">Βερολίνο</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="en">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="eo">Berlino</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="es">Berlín</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="et">Berliin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="eu">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="fa">برلین</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="fi">Berliini</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="fo">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="fr">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ga">Beirlín</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="gd">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="gl">Berlín</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="hbs">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="he">ברלין</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="hr">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="hu">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="hy">Բերլին</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ia">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="iata">BER</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="id">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="io">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="is">Berlín</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="it">Berlino</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ja">ベルリン</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="jv">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ka">ბერლინი</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ko">베를린</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ku">Berlîn</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="kw">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="la">Berolinum</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="lb">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="li">Berlien</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="link">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="lt">Berlynas</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="lv">Berlīne</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="mk">Берлин</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="mr">बर्लिन</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ms">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="nds">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="nl">Berlijn</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="nn">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="no">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="nrm">Bèrlîn</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="oc">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="pdc">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="pl">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="pms">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="pt">Berlim</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="qu">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="rm">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ro">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ru">Берлин</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="scn">Birlinu</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="sk">Berlín</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="sl">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="sq">Berlini</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="sr">Берлин</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="sv">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="sw">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ta">பெர்லின்</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="th">เบอร์ลิน</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="tr">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ty">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="ug">بېرلىن</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="uk">Берлін</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="vi">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="vo">Berlin</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="yi">בערלין</alternateName>
        <alternateName lang="zh">柏林</alternateName>
```

The XML-Header looks like this:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>`

The parsing itself works perfectly fine, except that a lot of the names are not displayed correctly due to a formatting issue. I tried UTF-8-encoding with no success.

My question now is what would be the correct way to encode the data so it is shown corretly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your device support respective font then you no problem if any specific font does not support by your device then you will not be able to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how you are loading the XML, which is probably where there problem lies if it's an encoding issue.

However, I think the problem is more likely to be that the font you are using to display the text doesn't support all of the characters sets for all of those languages. For example, if you are successfully seeing some non-latin words, but not others, then that is almost certainly the problem.

iOS does support font fallback to a certain extent, but different versions of iOS work differently in that regard, and looking at the range of character sets you've shown in that sample, I would be surprised if all of those character sets were supported.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but it looks like you are right with saying that my font does not support all the characters i need.

Comment: No problem. Better late than never. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding="ISO-8859-1" 
Take a look at this site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468560.aspx